# If $g(x+1)+g(x-1)=g(x)$ for all real $x$, then for what $p$ is $g(x+p)=g(x)$ necessarily true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $g(x)$ be a function such that $g(x+1) + g(x-1) = g(x)$ for every real $x$. Then for what value of $p$ is the relation $g(x+p) = g(x)$ necessarily true ?

I am unable to provide my solution approach for this problem as I was not able to move forward with this question. Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you need to find all such $p$? $p=0$ certainly satisfies the condition.

Comment: How did we get to "You have also $f(x+6)+f(x+3)=0$ for every real $x$, and therefore $f(x)=f(x+6)$ for every real $x$." in the first link you have provided? Can you please clarify me on this?

Comment: @Ganit added a response to your comment in the linked question.  Quickly going over it again here, since $g(x+1)+g(x-1)=g(x)$ is true for all $x$, it is similarly true that $g((x+1)+1)+g((x+1)-1)=g((x+1))$, giving $g(x+2)+g(x)=g(x+1)$ and similarly $g(x+3)+g(x+1)=g(x+2)$.  Moving to one side and adding, you have cancellations and so $g(x+3)+g(x)=0$.  Repeating the process gives the rest.